# Adding RestKit framework into Cathrag

Tags: ios, restkit, ibm-watson

why the RestKit framework is not adding in the cathrage for IOS, I have followed the exact instructions from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/ repo but not able to solve it. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, our documentation is a little out-of-date. Since v0.19.0 we have removed the `RestKit` framework. No need to build it or include it in your app.